# Unpivot the data based on certain conditions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

This is my table looks like

```
country     ID      weekyear    W1      W2      W3
------------------------------------------------------------
aa          1000    322015      0.00    4.50    0.00
bb          2000    262015      26.85   5.78    1.23
cc          3000    312015      0.94    0.00    2.90
dd          4000    362015      34.3    4.98    45.00
```

I have to unpivot the above table, but the challenge here is for example:

- For the `ID = 1000`, the `WEEKYEAR` says `322015` i.e. 32nd week of the year 2015. The very next value under `W1` denotes WEEK 33 and the next value under `W2` denotes WEEK 34 and so on.
- Similarly for the `ID = 2000`, `WEEKYEAR` says 26th week of 2015. So the next value under `W1` denotes 27th WEEK and the next value under `W2` is 28th week.

Kindly help unpivoting the table and the table looks exactly the same/

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: Don't bother being fancy and using unpivot. Just parse the weekyear string and use a couple of UNION ALLs with a little math. I don't understand what's so hard here and you have not shown any effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot your table:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3fcc/1/0)

```
SELECT
    t.country,
    t.ID,
    x.WeekYear,
    x.W
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES
    (WeekYear + 10000, W1),
    (WeekYear + 20000, W2),
    (WeekYear + 30000, W3)
)x(WeekYear, W)
```

Another way is to use `UNION ALL`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3fcc/2/0)

```
SELECT
    country, ID, WeekYear + 10000 AS WeekYear, W1 AS W
FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT
    country, ID, WeekYear + 20000 AS WeekYear, W2 AS W
FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT
    country, ID, WeekYear + 30000 AS WeekYear, W3 AS W
FROM tbl
ORDER BY country, ID, WeekYear
```